# Copying environment variables into Dockerfile

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create a .env-file in the Dockerfile using the following line:

```
RUN env | grep "REACT_APP" >> .env
```

I'm getting this error:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c env | grep "REACT_APP" >> .env' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

EDIT:

Full Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:11.2-alpine
EXPOSE 5000

ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn

RUN ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'env | grep "REACT_APP" >> .env']

RUN npm install -g serve
CMD serve -s build -n

# Separate layer for dependencies, it will speedup build
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build --production

#TODO: Maybe there is another way to include it to build?
#Legacy redirects via native serve options (https://github.com/zeit/serve-handler#redirects-array)
RUN cp serve.json build/
```

Comment: No errors when you execute it in your container, manually?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you don't have `REACT_APP` defined at all. As the command:

```
RUN env| grep REACT_APP >> .env
```

Will fail with the following error, in case you don't have it defined already.

```
The command '/bin/sh -c env| grep REACT_APP >> .env' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Also no need to write it as

```
RUN ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'env | grep "REACT_APP" >> .env']
```

This format `RUN env| grep REACT_APP >> .env` will suffice

Answer (score 0):

RUN command is launched "as-is", not through the shell. If you wish to use features like shell redirects you have to run it in the shell:

```
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "env | grep \"REACT_APP\" >> .env"]
```

`bash`, `dash`, `sh` - choose the shell you have in your image. Not every image has BASH inside.

Comment: It didn't work for me, I got another error: `/bin/sh: [/bin/sh,: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'env | grep "REACT_APP" >> .env']' returned a non-zero code: 127`. I also added the complete Dockerfile above so you can see.

Comment: My bad. I've put single instead of double quotes. Try again with this stanza. That's because RUN with argument list is paresed as a JSON list so the values inside must be JSON strings (which are defined in double-quotes).

Comment: The 127 disappeared and I got back to the original error: `The command '/bin/sh -c env | grep "REACT_APP" >> .env' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: `RUN` with just a string is automatically wrapped in `/bin/sh -c '...'`.  You don't usually need to manually include that in a Dockerfile like this.

Comment: @BluePrint That's because `grep` exits with code 1 if the match is not found.

Comment: @Szczad I understand now. Totally different problem than I thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are could be getting the error because you may not have "REACT_APP" env set.

can you try it as follows,

```
ENV REACT_APP test
RUN env | grep "REACT_APP" >> .env
```

You cant use bash as alphine image only support sh